# Searching for code in pull requests with GitHub API

Tags: git, github, github-api

Is it possible to search for code within pull requests of a repository using the GitHub API?

The `GET /search/code` endpoint does specify the following;

> Only the default branch is considered. In most cases, this will be the master branch.

But does this mean that only the code that has actually been merged is searchable, or is it possible to add keywords (like `in:pr`) to include pull requests as well?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the workaround using the [`gh` tool](https://cli.github.com/) (GitHub CLI).

```bash
gh pr list --state "all" --json 'number' --jq '.[].number' | xargs -i -- sh -c 'echo "PR number: {}" && gh pr diff --patch {} | grep "your text"'
```

Output

```
PR number: 203
+    base64_image_regex = /var s='(data:image\/[^;]+;base64,\S+)';var ii=\['#{img_id}'\]/
PR number: 202
PR number: 201
PR number: 200
PR number: 199
PR number: 198
PR number: 197
PR number: 196
PR number: 195
PR number: 194
PR number: 193
PR number: 192
PR number: 191
+      regex = /var s='(data:image\/[^']+)';var ii=\['#{image_id}'\];_setImagesSrc\(ii,s\);/
       regex = /var s='(data:image\/[^']+)';var ii=\['#{image_id}'\];_setImagesSrc\(ii,s\);/
-      regex = /var s='(data:image\/[^']+)';var ii=\['#{image_id}'\];_setImagesSrc\(ii,s\);/
PR number: 190
PR number: 189
PR number: 188
PR number: 187
PR number: 186
PR number: 185
PR number: 184
PR number: 183
PR number: 182
PR number: 181
PR number: 180
PR number: 179
PR number: 178
+    content.scan(/var s='(.*?)';var ii=\[(.*?)\];_setImagesSrc\(ii,s\);/).map do |link, ids|
PR number: 177
PR number: 176
PR number: 175
PR number: 174
```

*P.S. Currently, it misses the shell escaping of the string to be searched.*